# AWS Lambda RDS Database Connection Pooling

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am looking for AWS Lambda to handle RDS Database connection pooling mechanism or do we have work around for this????

If we not having option for this i will face max connection error quickly..

Comment: this can be useful https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=678029

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At last your query has been answered by AWS recently.

[Amazon RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/?sc_icampaign=Adoption_Campaign_pac_q419_sitemerch_RDSproxy_opensource&sc_ichannel=ha&sc_icontent=awssm-3540&sc_ioutcome=PaaS_Digital_Marketing&sc_iplace=signin&trk=ha_a131L0000058rveQAA~ha_awssm-3540&trkCampaign=pac_1219_console_RDSproxy_PDP)

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 3):

There are two aspects to the problem, I had similar issue and this is how I mitigated.

1. Reusing the database connection pooling, Following is an example where declaring the connection object outside of the handler will help for boost the hot starts

https://github.com/jeffnoehren/Spotinst-Function-Examples/blob/master/node-mysql-connection/handler.js

Here is a good read - http://blog.spotinst.com/2017/11/19/best-practices-serverless-connection-pooling-database/

2. second aspect of your problem, Reaching the maximum connections, no matter which connection pooling you are using if you don't throttle your lambda invocations there's a upper limit for the invocations. but you haven't mentioned how many requests you are handling. If your lambda invocations are asynchronous I would implement the request being enqueued in the SQS and consume those request asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

RDS Proxy has been released but its on Preview mode, it should handle your case

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-rds-proxy-available-in-preview/

Comment: Thanks awaited for long term for this.